# AMD Ryzen 5 2500U / Radeon Vega 8 Graphics drivers for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: amd-graphics

Does anyone know what additional drivers are required for "AMD Ryzen™ 5 2500U Mobile Processor with Radeon™ Vega 8 Graphics" on Ubuntu 18.04 ?

**EDIT 1**

### Additional information -

**Laptop model :** Acer Swift 3 (should also be applicable for **Dell Inspiron 15 5575**)

**Processor :** AMD Ryzen™ 5 2500U Mobile Processor

**GPU :** Radeon™ Vega 8 (Integrated)

### Queries / Issues -

- Fractional scaling not available (How to ?)
- Display resolution 1600x900 not available (How to ?)
- Does it need any additional GPU driver (e.g. AMDGPU Pro) ?

#### Acer community thread on this topic [link](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/549486/acer-swift-3-ryzen-5-vega-8-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: There are no additional drivers needed. Fractional scaling has nothing to do with drivers, and it is available (though the GNOME UI might not allow it). Display resolution should be fine, assuming the display supports it.

Comment: On windows 10, 1600x900 is available and works fine. But the same is not available on Ubuntu / Linux Mint. I tried to add the resolution manually but it resulted in blank screen (http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/)

Comment: OK. The timings were probably wrong then. You are trying to use that resolution on the internal display? If so, why instead of the native resolution of the panel?

Comment: Because this laptop has a 1920x1080 display, and using the full resolution its almost not usable as the fonts are very small. Hence the solution would be to have fractional scaling (125%, windows has this) or using a lower display resolution like 1600x900 .

Comment: Why not use gnome tweak tool to increase fractional scaling. Ubuntu also has option to increase scaling to 125% but it is hidden, i had done it a year ago almost.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still struggling with display resolution (tiny font) on Linux, here is what i did on my Linux Mint 19 (i switched to Mint).

Open `control center`, click on `Appearance`, go to `Fonts` tab, make sure `Subpixel smoothing (LCDs)` is selected and click on the `Details` button.

Under `Resolution`, turn off `Automatic Detection`, then change the `Dots per inch (DPI)` value to 120 (works pretty well in my case, fine tune the value according to your need).

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

**Firefox:**

Make the following changes if you use Firefox.

Open `Firefox`, then type `about:config` in the address bar and hit enter, click on `I accept the risk`, on the next page, search for `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` and modify the value to `1.3`.

[image]

Comment: Hi
Where do I find this options in Ubuntu 18? (Appearance preferences)