# How to install drivers for graphic card Radeon AMD Ryzen 7 VGA Picasso

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

I got a Lenovo Ideapad L340-15API and the webpages are not displaying correctly either in mozilla or chromium. They display centered in a limited area.
Also the general size of all graphics and fonts in Ubuntu 18 is reduced.
I tryed by changing the screen resolution size, but didnt work.
I want to check if the drivers ar OK to thiscard this as a possible reazon or fix it.
Thank you.

This is what comes after inxi -Gx:

> Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Picasso bus-ID: 03:00.0
>              Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.5 ) driver: amdgpu
>              Resolution: 1920x1080@60.01hz
>              OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.33.0, 5.3.0-26-generic, LLVM 9.0.0)
>              version: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.1 Direct Render: Yes

You can see in the attached immage how the web pages are displaying

Does this makes any sense?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: scale by 200%.? in settngs, display properties

Comment: Hi @pierrely
Thanks. That doesnt work (too big)

Comment: how about power key, tweaks, fonts, scaling factor.

Comment: I used Unity Tweak Tool to increase fonts, also in Firefox changed "about:config" in the address bar and and searched for layout.css.devPixelsPerPx and modify the value to 1.4 (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054077/amd-ryzen-5-2500u-radeon-vega-8-graphics-drivers-for-ubuntu-18-04)
So yes, the desk looks good now but some immages in the web pages are pixelated

Comment: Maybe if I coudl change the resolution up to 1366 x 768 but that option is not in the settings